# Regex to split a String by ; but not amp;

Tags: regex

I have a String needs to be split by semi-colon. The easiest way to go is `[^;]+`. By using this, every semi-colon in the string will be used as a delimiter.

However, in our string, there are some "&" that we do not want to include that ; as a delimiter.

For example, a String

```
abcd;efg;hij&amp;kl;mn
```

The expected result would be `abcd, efg, hij&amp;kl, mn`

Can some one help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match everything outside of "real `;`s":

```
(?:&amp;|[^;])+
```

would work. Or `(?:&\w+;|[^;])+` if more than just `&amp;` entities are to be expected.

If your regex engine supports split operations, perhaps this regex (matching semicolons only if not preceded by `&amp`) is also a good idea

```
(?<!&amp);
```

To also allow other entities like above, `(?<!&\w+);` can be used if your regex implementation supports indefinite repetition inside [lookbehind assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Most don't, though, .NET being an exception.

In Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall("(?:&amp;|[^;])+", "abcd;efg;hij&amp;kl;mn")
['abcd', 'efg', 'hij&amp;kl', 'mn']
>>> re.split("(?<!&amp);", "abcd;efg;hij&amp;kl;mn")
['abcd', 'efg', 'hij&amp;kl', 'mn']
```

Answer (score 3):

I think better approach is to decode your string (for example in .NET [`HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx) method, I don't know your platform), then split by `;`.

Regex:

```
(?<!&[^;]+);
```

It will ignore not only `&amp;` but any other HTML/XML special symbols started with `&` and ended with `;`.

Comment: It is a good way to go, however, due to the limitation of the code, I cann't perform anything to decode the String. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If your regex flavour allows it then use a negative look behind

```
(?<!&amp);
```

See it [here online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2um9l)

This will only match if there is no `&amp` before a `;`

Here is a Java example to use split

```
String str = "abcd;efg;hij&amp;kl;mn";
String[] Result = str.split("(?<!&amp);");
```